# how to generate graphics from python (or printable tables)?

Tags: python, printing

I would like to write in python a generator of multiplication tables for my children. I imagine something like a 10x10 table with 20 or 30 of the cells randomly bolded (a thicker border). What would be a good method to generate the printable output?

I am tentatively thinking of generating a `LaTeX` file but there may be a simpler (more pythonic, less dependencies) solution?

*UPDATE: if someone is interested in the code to generate the above [I posted it to bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/WoJ/tablesmult). This is an alpha version form a "Sunday developper" as we say in France (which means that the code is ugly and that you must not use in any circumstances when developing space shuttle management software :))*

Comment: You might be interested in the [`pythontex`](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex) package for LaTeX, which allows you to include Python code in your LaTeX documents, run the code, and include the output in the document. See the [gallery](https://github.com/gpoore/pythontex/tree/master/pythontex_gallery) for an example of a calculus table generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use HTML and CSS instead of Latex, it's a little bit simpler and cleaner, and just as printable.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style> 
    table {border-collapse: collapse}
    td { border:1px solid black; }
    td.bolded { border:3px solid black }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> 1 </td> <td> 2 </td> <td class="bolded"> 3 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean, obvious and easy solution!